# Is it grammatically acceptable to drop "to" in constructions such as [to cater "to" someone] and [to entitle someone "to" something]?

Tags: grammar, american-english, word-usage

Back when I was a student, I was taught as a rule that verbs such as "cater" and "entitle" should be followed by "to" before "someone" and "something" respectively.

Yet, I was kind of puzzled the other day when browsing the Net I came across instances of prepositionless constructions around these verbs, and so I wish you could tell whether or not these sound grammatical to you.

> Utah will cater you all that you have wanted in a perfect vacation.
>   [source](http://www.altiusdirectory.com/Travel/utah-travel-guide.php)
>
> I started sideRACK.net at the beginning of the 2009 recession and a means to cater you the group of people who love boutique clothing. [source](http://www.examiner.com/article/fashion-rising-siderack-net)
>
> There are also special toilets available to cater physically challenged individuals. [source](http://www.keepitplanned.com/times-union-centre-jacksonville-fl/)
>
> Geriatricians cater the elderly people.
>   [source](http://www.doctors-look.com/Geriatrician.html)
>
> Black men endured as slaves entitled them the right to vote before women.
>   [source](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/lesson-of-the-2008-election-is-that-sexism-is-still-more-pervasive-than-racism/)
>
> The right of citizenship merely entitles them the right to return to their homeland.
>   [source](http://www.ourcampaigns.com/NewsDetail.html?NewsID=66989&WhenStart=2010-05-01+17:07:27)
>
> The First Amendment constitutionally protected free speech in 1790, but the right to free speech in those days merely entitled you the right to...
>   [source](http://www.theamericanphilosopher.com/2012/09/26/free-speech-and-the-innocence-of-muslims/)
>
> FERPA entitles you the right of confidentiality.
>   [source](http://www2.bgsu.edu/offices/sa/ferpa/page51372.html)
>
> Workbook entitles you the right to download, mix match and print as many copies as you need for the current school year. [source](http://chinuch.org/static_files/Chumash.pdf)
>
> And entitles you the right to be in the running for board positions. [source](http://www.nwacc.edu/c/document_library/get_file?uuid=3e0db454-b841-44e9-94f5-4e12b7cd6dd4&groupId=289967)
>
> whether at governmental offices or in private sector, and to reside as long as you want also entitles you the right to set up your own business. 
>   [source](http://www.immigrationvisahelp.com/immigration-to-usa/)
>
> Your payment of the investment to us entitles you the right to a seat. [source](http://globalachieversacademy.com/terms-and-conditions-of-purchase/)

*Cater v. tr. [to attend to the wants and needs of]*

> http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cater

Comment: That doesn't sound like fluent American English at all. Most of those sites look poorly-edited and several look like they were not written by Americans. It might be a good idea to name your sources when quoting them instead of just linking to them. And again, please offer your own analysis rather than just linking to examples. (Also, in trimming some of the quotations, you have made them even more ungrammatical.)

Comment: NG: Is it OK for me drop *to* after me?  It would be most welcome you would use some common sense before you asking these questions. I know you to understand me. ')

Comment: Il me semble que tout le monde trouve que tes questions sont un peu bizarre, mais je commence devenir un fan. Ils sont tout à fait inspiré !

Comment: @Jim Comment ça tu les trouves bizarres? Je demande tout bonnement si telle ou telle construction grammaticale est acceptable ou non en AE, c'est tout. ;)

Comment: Jim: “I think everyone finds that your questions are a little weird, but I'm starting to become a fan. They are quite inspirational!” NG: “How do you find them funny? I ask simply whether a particular grammatical construction is acceptable or not in AE, that's all.”

Comment: Yes, so NG, I don't want to drop off into another language for too long. It's not really appropriate, even in the comments (but thanks, Bradd, for translating). But I find something interesting in your assorted questions, but I can't quite put my finger on it yet.

Comment: @Jim I think that NG has asked this and other questions because he sees it in use online.  I can see how, as a non-native speaker, he lacks the filter to determine that these are ungrammatical on his own.

Comment: ùSusan If it's grammatically OK to drop "with" after "supply", "furnish", "provide", "feed", etc, then why wouldn't it be acceptable to do so with "to" in such constructions as "cater to someone" and "entitle someone to something"?

Comment: @NourishedGourmet Clearly you are asking these questions with good intent.  But, I think it might help people to understand your posts if you were to clarify why you were asking them, etc.  You could do this either in the question itself, or if you are asking these questions in preparation for another purpose, you could perhaps make a meta post explaining your needs.  It might help win people over when you post some more "obscure" findings.

Comment: @David - I agree. I've been wondering if these questions are more appropriate for ELL, but I'm not convinced of that. In the mean time, NG, keep them coming.

Comment: I would rather see him post in [meta] for advice about better ways to tackle this subject in general. As it is, he's posting a lot of borderline-topical stuff. Some of it turns out to be interesting, but I think a native speaker would react to most of it like, “Why would you ever think that was OK?” I suspect that [ell.se] is a better fit for the latter stuff.

Comment: @Bradd, yes, but as a foreign language student myself, I am often frustrated by answers like I might get at a site like wordreference.com (which is a wonderful site), such as "we would never say that". They don't provide the technical background that might be obtained here.

Comment: Basic problem is that you're not factoring in predicate government. Whether prepositions occur, and which ones, are governed almost entirely by the predicates and their idioms. Not by the constructions, by and large. So you're mixing up lots of phenomena because you aren't making enough distinctions between predicates. Levin is a good start, but there's lots more to learn.

Comment: @John I'd like to say "my thoughts exactly" but I couldn't really put it all together fully in my mind. Yes, there's a lot to learn. Can you elaborate on who Levin is, please? I generally like to look at your references, and they sometimes take awhile just to begin to comprehend.

Comment: Okay, I got Beth Levin, but where to begin with respect to your comment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to give a short answer to this.

None of the constructions you've given above appear grammatical.

To *cater* without *to* in this way is to provide food for a party.

> Nourished Gourmet won the contract to cater the banquet.

To *cater to* means to attend to their needs.

Entitle does occasionally get used that way.  But, I'm not sure if it's grammatical.